# Soundboard time limitation

Tags: android, eclipse

For my first app and introduction to eclipse I decided to create a little soundboard with the help of an existing code provided along with a tutorial here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fg2dchQ3Pg8

It works fine but the only issue is that my sounds do not last more than 6 seconds whatever the audio format I use for audio files (ogg, mp3...)

Do you have any idea where my problem come from?

Thanks a lot for your help, I would really appreciate it.

Have a good day

Comment: People don't have time to go off watching tutorials, you need to post your code showing the problem here.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for the quick feedback. Sorry I'm quite a noob and do not know which part of the code to send since I don't know where the problem come from. Would it be in the layout? main activity?                Thanks